# Java Scanner does not expect next input, ignores nextLine()

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I don't really get the behaviour of the Scanner. I want to input a single int first and in the while-loop, as you can see, next line inputs. But after the first input I get an ArrayOutOfBoundsException as you can see below. It just ignores that I want to input next lines. The only solution is when I input the int and the new line separated with a space in one line, but that isn't what I want, because at this point, the user doesn't know, what to input after the first int.

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        int i = scanner.nextInt() - 1;
        logic.setGameField(games.get(i).getGameField());

//      scanner.reset(); //what does that do?

        view.displayField(logic.getCompleteGameField(), logic.getGameSize(), logic.getCompleteGameSize());

        double time = System.currentTimeMillis();


        while (!logic.gameIsFinished()) {
            System.out.println("Spalte Reihe Zeichen: X/*");

            String s = scanner.nextLine();

            char[] tmp = s.toCharArray(); 

            //just for testing
            System.out.println(s.length()); //outputs: 0
            System.out.println(tmp.length); //outputs: 0
            for (int j = 0; j < tmp.length; j++) {
                System.out.print(tmp[j] + " " + j);     
            }
            System.out.println();

            logic.setSingleField(tmp[1] - CHAR_TO_INT_OFFSET_ROW, tmp[0] - CHAR_TO_INT_OFFSET_COLUMN, tmp[2]); //throws as expected ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException
```

Comment: `System.out.println(s.length()); //outputs: 0` so what do you expect when using `tmp[2]`, `tmp[1]` or `tmp[0]`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because Scanner.nextInt() doesn't bring you to the next line. At this point, you are still in current line of input. What you can do is call an additional Scanner.nextLine() after Scanner.nextInt():

```
int i = scanner.nextInt() - 1;
scanner.nextLine();
logic.setGameField(games.get(i).getGameField());
```

Comment: Thanks, that did help!